# Why is Component.onCompleted called twice?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, pyside6

Consider the QML code below:

```
// Test1.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Label {
    text: "Hello"
    Component.onCompleted: console.log("Label")
}
```

I preview the effect by using pyside6-qml in a PySide6 virtual environment, and get:

```
qml: Label
qml: Label
```

Why is Component.onCompleted called twice?

However, if the type Label is replaced by type Window:

```
// Test2.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window

Window {
    visible: true
    Component.onCompleted: console.log("Window")
}
```

Only one log is printed:

```
qml: Window
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with Qt 6.4.1 on Linux with the qml command. How do you run it? What Qt version? What platform?

Comment: @LucaCarlon I run it with the pyside6-qml command (installed with PySide 6.5.0 by pip). If I run it with qml command (installed by the Qt installer), Component.onCompleted is called once in each case. My OS is Windows 11.